# Adding a variable to the PATH variable not translating

Tags: windows, environment-variables, mdt

I have a bunch of applications that I install using MDT packages.
One of the packages needs an entry to the PATH variable.
I would like to add a variable to the PATH variable. But this variable is not being translated.

My example:
I would like to add a location to PATH: C:\Program Files\gs\gs9.55.0\bin
Since this location uses a versionnumber, I find it easier to manage when I can create an extra variable. So I created an extra variable called GS_HOME with this location and added %GS_HOME% to PATH.

[image: GS_HOME variable]
[image: Added variable in PATH]

When doing this manually, everything works fine. I test this by doing "echo %path%" and it gives me the PATH result with the translated %GS_HOME% variable
[image: Translated GS_HOME variable in PATH]

The problem: When doing this via MDT, I can add the %GS_HOME% value just fine, and it shows up exactly the same in PATH. BUT the "echo %path%" test does not translate the %GS_HOME% variable.
[image: GS_HOME not translated]

For extra info. I use these commands to create/modify the variables:

```
powershell -command "[Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable(‘Path’, $env:Path + “;%GS_HOME%”, [EnvironmentVariableTarget]::Machine)"

cmd /c setx /M GS_HOME "C:\Program Files\gs\gs9.55.0\bin
```

Comment: Did you try to execute the two commands in reverse order?

Comment: Your Powershell command is using smart quotes. Don't do that.